# Unable to detect Wifi but no internet connection

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, cordova

I have developed a sencha touch based application using salesoforce mobile sdk 2.2.1.
I am using cordova's following inbuild function for network state change

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline

These work fine when my app changes from internet to no internet condition, **but fails when there is Wifi but no internet condition**.

Does anyone know how to fix that? as we can't update cordova in SalesforceMobileSDK.

It's very urgent, please let me know for any solution or work around.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Regards, 
Manish Kumar

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Cordova is just monitoring when the device moves on or off a Wifi network and makes no assurances about connectivity.

Surely the best connectivity test is the same it's always been: just try to ping a server somewhere?